# Why Spellcheck input does not work on IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

Spellcheck work on IE11 like that:

```
<input name="test"   spellcheck="true" ></input>
```

But if i add "pattern", Spellcheck does not work anymore:

```
<input name="test"   spellcheck="true"  pattern=".*"></input>
```

Has anyone seen a similar problem before?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with IE 11 and find that spell check is not working in combination with pattern.

I try to search for the solution but did not got anything.

I also tested with other browsers like Edge(Edge HTML), Chrome and new Edge(Chromium). In that I had find that it is working in Chrome and new Edge(Chromium) and has similar issue with MS Edge(Edge HTML). I had already provided a feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue.

As IE will not receive any feature updates so we can expect that this issue will remain in IE.

As a work around for IE, you can keep the spell check there but try to match the pattern using JavaScript may help to avoid the issue.

Reference:

[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)